How do you deserialise JSON in Rust without coupling
I'm very new to Rust. I'm trying to write a JSON wrapper (trait) so that callers across my program are not coupled to a specific implementation, but can instead require the trait to be Dependency Injected. DI is a non-negotiable for any code I write, fyi.
This is my trait:
use crate::utils::traits::custom_errors::json::TJsonError as TCustomJsonError;

pub trait TJsonParser {
  fn parse<T>(&self, json_string: &str) -> Result<T, Box<dyn TCustomJsonError>>;
}

And here's my implementation so far, for which I'm trying serde:
use serde_json;
// other imports removed for brevity;

pub struct JsonParser;

impl TJsonParser for JsonParser {
    fn parse<T>(&self, json_string: &str) -> Result<T, Box<dyn TCustomJsonError>> {
        match serde_json::from_str(json_string) {
            Ok(value) => Ok(value),
            Err(err) => Err(Box::new(CustomJsonError(format!("Error parsing JSON: {}", err)))),
        }
    }
}

The problem I'm facing is the compiler complains about serde_json::from_str(json_string) saying:

the trait bound T: Deserialize<'_> is not satisfied. Deserialize<'_> is not implemented for T

In C# for example, I can do this:
public interface IJsonParser
{
    T Parse<T>(string jsonString);
}
// ...

using NewtonsoftJsonConvert = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert;
public class JsonParser : IJsonParser
{
    public T Parse<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        T value = NewtonsoftJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
        return value;
    }
}

It's not simply because C# supports reflection that this is possible. Typescript does not have reflection, but I can still do this:
interface IJsonParser {
  Parse<T>(jsonString: string): T
}

class JsonParser implements IJsonParser {
  Parse<T>(jsonString: string): T {
    let parsed_obj = JSON.parse(jsonString)
    // Use validation library to validate parsed_obj as T and return as T.
  }
}

In either language, I can define a wrapper abstraction without having to put constraints (attributes, bounds, call it what you may) on the generic parameters or my domain types (structs, interfaces, types, call it what you may).
I suspect this whole issue arises from serde being inflexible by forcing type constraints.
Questions:

Maybe I'm mistaken, but I feel like I need to specify a where trait bound in the definition for parse and then attribute all my structs that need to be deserialised to, with #[derive(Deserialize)]. Is this correct?
If the answer to #1 is (more or less) "yes", then how can I create a wrapper such that I do not need to attribute my domain structs with implementation (serde or such) details or reference implementation when specifying bounds in my trait definition? This is the whole point of creating a wrapper to begin with.


serde_json::from_str can only be used with types that implement Deserialize. Full stop.

Your C# code works because it has reflection (i.e. can inspect fields and types at runtime). Rust does not have this.

@kmdreko Thanks, I had a feeling this was the case but wasn't sure. So given no RTTI in Rust, are there any libraries besides serde that can circumvent the need for your structs to implement specific traits? Or is it quite simply: if deserialising in Rust, your structs MUST implement specific traits (through attributes or otherwise)?

If you're trying to keep separation of concerns as clear as possible, you may want to leave your "domain" type untouched and create a separate DTO (data transfer object) type that is used for external interop (and have conversions between). Some don't like that due to the boilerplate (though I personally prefer it), but that's the best recommendation I have if you don't want to add "implementation details" to those types.

@kmdreko Interesting approach. Thanks. I'll ponder on this for a bit...

You can also deserialise arbitrary JSON as Value without knowing its structure, if that helps.

Beware of trying to force OO patterns into Rust. Rust is not OO, and many times the way to achieve general software good practices (such as loose coupling here) is not quite the same as in OO languages.

@kmdreko Perhaps I'm missing something here but even with DTOs, wouldn't the implementation (JsonParser) need to declare a where T: serde::... (or such) to have it compile? But then the compiler would also need this bound defined in the trait (TJsonParser) as well? If that's the case then that won't work as now the trait becomes coupled to serde.

@jthulhu Since I'm new to Rust, it's quite possible I'm trying to force OO paradigms to achieve general software good practices. Feel free to suggest alternate techniques to achieve loose coupling, easy refactoring, and unit-testability in Rust.

@eggyal Could you please elaborate (with an answer perhaps) on how you'd use Value here? If it means no reference to serde in the trait (TJsonParser) or the domain structs, then I'd be happy with the implementation.

It does, but you won't be able to return T (without it being constrained to something that can convert from Value).  If that's acceptable to you, then I'd have TJsonParser have an associated type, say type Deserialized; and its parse method would then return Self::Deserialized in the result.  The implementation for the serde parser would then set that associated type to Value.

@eggyal It might make more sense to me if I see the code you are proposing. If you want to post an answer I can comment there. Thanks!

@eggyal An associated type that I define to which T is constrained is fine. I don't want it to be constrained to something from a library (like serde or such).

I won't post as an answer because it doesn't really answer your question as posed. However you can see it on the playground.

You can read this document on Rust patterns.

@eggyal Thanks. Could you also add usage? Perhaps with a struct Person {name: String, age: u32,}, and json string "{"name": "John", "age": 30}"?

@jthulhu Doesn't help. There's no alternative suggested for DI. Closest is (the badly presented) discussion on Strategy pattern (https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/strategy.html#discussion), in which closures are suggested, where the crux of it is providing (better word to follow) a custom adder function as an argument to a generic Adder implementation. Better word: injected. So if the intention was to say "don't need DI", then it's contradicting itself by using DI.

@jthulhu Feel free to suggest an approach as an answer to how I would be able to easily refactor code or be able to unit test code that directly referenced serde (i.e, not using DI).

@kmdreko Have edited my question to reflect on reflection.

JavaScript (TypeScript) also has reflection, but actually what it does you can do too in Rust by deserializing into serde_json::Value. It does not deserialize into a typed struct.

Honestly, I don't understand what is the problem with just adding a serde::Deserialize bound. Yes, this couples you to serde. But does this make your code untestable? I don't think so.

If you really want, you can have a ParseType factory that you can mock with a bound, but this feels like just duplicating what is already the purpose of TJsonParser (unless it also does other things).

@ChayimFriedman Other than Object.keys(), Javascript's reflection is weak. As mentioned in my question, DI is non-negotiable. Perhaps the creators of Rust and/or serde should've paid more attention to the 'D' in SOLID. No, under no circumstance will I couple my trait definition (the abstract wrapper which is meant to be independent to implementation) to serde or any other lib. If that's the case then my only option is to ditch Rust.

SOLID are OO design patterns, Rust isn't OOP though. I don't see how it would be relevant. If you want to do OOP then yea, Rust probably isn't the right choice for you.

@cafce25  Wrong. Common misconception. And seems like a Rusty excuse in order to avoid it. SOLID is applicable to any programming paradigm not just OO. DI specifically ought to be used everywhere. Unless you're happy with maintaining crap code.

@Ash The key difference between class based languages and trait/typeclass based languages for SOLID, is that in a class based language, the data+behaviour is a single item, in a trait/typeclass they are seperate items, which means just because you have a dependency on the data, does not mean you have a dependency on the behaviour, unless you specifically reference that typeclass. You can still do dependency injection in rust. But you do it using compile time generics implementing traits like Deserialise.

You don't dependency inject the trait. You dependency inject the type as fulfilling the trait. Trying to dependency inject traits is a fundamental misunderstanding of what traits are.

But often people go back to the core. Why do you need decoupling in OOP? To manage side effects. Because you need to be able to replace the side effects structure. Well if you write pure functional code, you have no side effects. Minimal need to mock and all you care about is the inputs and outputs.

@user1937198 Even with functional, you end up with HOFs that rely on abstract arguments to other pure functions, and guess what, that’s DI. SOLID is sentiment not semantics.

@user1937198 "You don't dependency inject the trait. You dependency inject the type as fulfilling the trait." Sure. Though so far I've only heard theories of how to avoid coupling. Yet to see any actual code with usage.

First off, I just want to say that Rust is not going to perfectly fit your use case. While I am going to propose a solution, keep in mind there are 2 big drawbacks that will be difficult to overcome.
Generally, the key point I want to emphasize is that in every language you will be coupling with something to perform serialization/deserialization. In most languages, JSON parsing is implemented by coupling to core language or runtime features (generally some sort of reflection). Rust does not provide this, so you must find something else to couple to instead. People are willing to couple their code to serde since it is seen as one of the most stable/reliable crates within the entire Rust ecosystem. Personally, I recommend biting the bullet and coupling with serde, but I do also go through a different approach.
Approach
I think the core issue with the code you attempted is where you put the generic. If you put the generic inside the trait you run into the issues you encountered were you can not impose additional bounds on T within different implementations. In Rust we instead want to raise the generic to the trait itself so we can pick and choose what types it gets implemented for. This also solves a common issue with OOP languages where it is easy to hide interface requirements behind layers of abstraction. Here is an example of roughly what I am proposing.
pub trait TJsonParser<T> {
    type Error: TCustomJsonError;

    fn parse(&self, json_string: &str) -> Result<T, Self::Error>;
}

trait TCustomJsonError {
    // etc.
}

Going into this, we know that some types simply will not be deserializable by all TJsonParsers. For example, this might include types imported via FFI that can only be handled by SpecialFfiJsonParser. We need to provide some way of telling the compiler which types we can and can't work with for static analysis to actually help us. If we want to add a parser for serde_json, we would write it like this.
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;

pub struct JsonParser;

impl<T: DeserializeOwned> TJsonParser<T> for JsonParser {
    type Error = serde_json::Error;

    fn parse(&self, json_string: &str) -> Result<T, Self::Error> {
        serde_json::from_str(json_string)
    }
}

impl TCustomJsonError for serde_json::Error {}

In effect, we are really just making a wrapper for serde::Deserialize that lets us decouple the code from our approach.
Flaws
How do we get type-specific information?
The biggest flaw that I think some of the commenters were getting at is that no matter what approach you use, you need to have some way of conveying information about the type being deserialized to the parser. In other languages, this is done by coupling the implementation with the language or runtime itself (usually via reflection). We don't normally think about this as coupling since it normally is not possible for this coupling to break. In the case of Rust, we do not have a system provided by the language to couple to, so we need to use something else.
This is where we run into issues. Broadly speaking, we need some sort of trait to depend on (ideally one that we can derive on types as needed). In the case of serde, this comes in the form of Serialize and Deserialize. However, we also have other choices like crates that derive traits for performing general reflection. However, regardless of what you choose you need to couple to something. Many projects/libraries choose to couple to serde as it is seen as one of the most stable packages within the entire Rust ecosystem.
In an attempt to break this coupling, we could do the same thing we do everywhere else and create a wrapper. One way to do this would be to make your own derive proc macro for JsonParsable types.
This works in part because there is no restriction that JsonParsable derive a single trait implementation or that the traits being derived even be called JsonParsable. For example, take this code.
/// Depending on the requirements of parsers the given structure, this could
/// derive `serde::Deserialize` and `other_library::Deserialize`.
#[derive(JsonParsable)]
struct Foo { /* etc. */ }

/// Perhaps you have some issues with `serde`, so this type can only derive
/// `other_library::Deserialize`.
#[derive(JsonParsable)]
struct Bar { /* etc. */ }

A necessary part of implementing TJsonParser would be updating JsonParsable to derive any additional trait requirements. In this approach you would be coupling to JsonParsable, but at least it is your own library so it is less of an issue. I do not think there is any way to distribute parser-specific derives outside of JsonParsable without making your own build system wrapper. However, I highly advise against this as you would just be moving the coupling into your build system and likely introducing numerous anti-patterns in the process.
Exploding trait dependencies
The other issue you will encounter is trait dependencies piling up. I think the easiest way to express this is with an example.
fn handle_foo<J>(parser: &J)
    where J: TJsonParser<Foo> { /* etc. */ }

fn handle_bar<J>(parser: &J)
    where J: TJsonParser<Bar> { /* etc. */ }

fn handle_baz<J>(parser: &J)
    where J: TJsonParser<Baz> { /* etc. */ }

/// Handles Foo, Bar, and Baz requests
fn handle_request<J>(parser: &J)
    where J: TJsonParser<Foo> + TJsonParser<Bar> + TJsonParser<Baz>,
{ /* etc. */ }

If you want to implement a web server, it is easy to imagine that there will end up being a ton of TJsonParser<...> requirements piling up on every generic function going up the dependency tree. One way we can mitigate this is with wrapper traits, but it is more of a bandaid than a solution.
/// We can now use RequestJsonParser as a stand in for this group of requirements.
pub trait RequestJsonParser: TJsonParser<Foo> + TJsonParser<Bar> + TJsonParser<Baz> {}

impl<T> RequestJsonParser for T
    where T: TJsonParser<Foo> + TJsonParser<Bar> + TJsonParser<Baz> {}

/// Handles Foo, Bar, and Baz requests
fn handle_request<J>(parser: &J)
    where J: RequestJsonParser,
{ /* etc. */ }

There are RFCs in the works that would improve this issue (such as requiring a trait map 1-1 with another trait; for<B: Sized> T: TJsonParser<B>), but don't expect anything soon.

Thank you for the answer. Upvoted. I think I follow most of it. I certainly saw trait dependencies piling up as soon as I saw the generic type being moved from the parse function to the trait definition. This would be the case in other languages as well. At the composite (IoC) root, this may also mean separate registration for each impl type. Let me digest a bit more...
